# CSS transformation with object

Tags: css, html, menu, transform

I have a question regarding CSS transformation. I made a Dropdown menu in which the dropdown (submenu) should have a special shape. See here:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5Ki_dh4A-VJY2ZKQUJaQnF5SDQ&usp=sharing

So far I could manage a part of it with: `transform: skewY`. How I can finish the rest as shown in the picture above?

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxfxs/

Has anybody an idea?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MENUTEST</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <style>
        #menu {
            font-family: TrajanProRegular;
            position: absolute;
            top:100px;
            width: 1100px;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: #484441;
            color: #8C8985;
            font-weight: bold;
            clear: both;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 70px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        nav {
            width: 1100px;
            height: 70px;
            background: #484441;
            line-height: 70px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        nav span {
            font: 1.35em 'TrajanProRegular';
        }

        nav a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        nav ul {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: -1px;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        ul li {
            font: 9px  'PT Sans Narrow';
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -moz-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -ms-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -o-transition: padding .05s linear;
            transition: padding .05s linear;
        }
        ul li.drop {
            position: relative;
        /*        float: left;*/
        }
        ul > li {
               display: inline-block;
               letter-spacing: 0.11em;
               padding: 0 10px 0;
        }
        ul li a {
            line-height: 70px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            height: 70px;
            color: #8C8985;
            font: 1.3em/70px TrajanProRegular;
            /* font: 10pt/70px TrajanProBold; */
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-out;
            border-left: 1px solid #777370;
            border-right: 1px solid #777370;
        }
        ul li a:hover {
            color: #eee;
        }

        .dropOut .triangle {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-left: 8px solid transparent;
            border-right: 8px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #239976;
            top: -8px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -8px;
        }
        .dropdownContain {
            width: 160px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -80px; /* half of width */
            top: -400px;
        }
        .dropOut {
            width: 185px;
            background: #239976;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-out;
           -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
           -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
           -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
           -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
           transform: skewY(3deg);
        }

        .dropOut ul {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px 0;
            -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
            -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
            -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
            -o-transform: skewY(-3deg);
            transform: skewY(-3deg);
        }

        .dropOutb {
            width: 185px;
            background: #239976;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-out;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .dropOut ul li {
            text-align: left;
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            /* padding: 12px 0 10px 15px; */
            margin: 0px 3px;
            color: #FFF;
           /* -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            * -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            * border-radius: 4px;
            */
            -webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: background .1s ease-out;
        }
        /* NEW */
        .dropOut ul li a{
            font: 12px 'PT Sans Narrow';
            border: none !important;
            /* padding: 5px 0 10px 0px !important; */
            text-align: left;
            width: 160px !important;
            margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
            padding: 5px 0 10px 0px !important;
            float: left;
            height: 15px !important;
            -webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -moz-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -ms-transition: padding .05s linear;
            -o-transition: padding .05s linear;
            transition: padding .05s linear;
        }


        .dropOut ul li:hover {
            /* background: #CCE5DB; */
            /* text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFFFFF; */
            /* filter:DropShadow(Color=#fffff, OffX=2, OffY=2); */
        }
        .dropOut ul li:hover a {
            color: #ACD6C6;
        }

        ul li:hover a { color: white; }
        ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
        ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
        ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px; }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="menu">
           <nav>
               <ul>
                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu1</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut dropOutb">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">T1Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">T1Sub2</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu2</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut dropOutb">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">Topmenu2sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Topmenu2sub2</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu3</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">TOPmenu3Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">TOPmenu3Sub2</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu4</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu4Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu4Sub2</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu4Sub3</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu4Sub4</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu5</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu5Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu5Sub2</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu5Sub3</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu5Sub4</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu5Sub5</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu6</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">TOPmenu6Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="kontakt.html">TOPmenu6Sub2</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->

                   <li class="drop">
                       <a href="#"><span>T</span>OPmenu7</a>
                       <div class="dropdownContain">
                           <div class="dropOut">
                               <!--<div class="triangle"></div>-->
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu7Sub1</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu7Sub2</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#" target="contLiFrame">TOPmenu7Sub3</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div> <!-- dropOut -->
                       </div> <!-- dropdownContain -->
                   </li> <!-- drop -->
               </ul>
           </nav>               
       </div><!-- menu -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for code improvement @jsve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add the following to `.dropOut ul`

```
background: #239976;
margin-bottom: -10px;
margin-top: 10px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/sxfxs/1/

Comment: thank you sooooo much! I thought it will complicated and trick but you could fix it simple and nicely!

Big Thanks to you!